# Backgammon game competition.

Tags: probability

Two players $A$ and $B$ compete in a certain backgammon game. The competition is conducted in "Rounds" where each "Round" consists of $5$ single backgammon games. A round is won by the player who has more winnings in $5$ single games and final winner is the one who will first earn $12$ rounds.

[image]

Due to previous experience the probability that player $A$ wins in a single game against $B$ is $0,6$ but in order $A$ to challenge his opponent $B$, he offers him $5$ rounds won at the beginning of the competition. Is $A$ still reasonable that he will win the final prize of the competition? More precisely, what is the probability that $A$ will win?

I computed that
$$
\eqalign{
P[A\ win\ a\ round] &= \binom{5}{3}0.6^3\cdot 0.4^2 + \binom{5}{4}0.6^4\cdot 0.4^1 \binom{5}{5}0.6^5\cdot 0.4^0 \cr
&= 0.68256 \cr
}
$$

Comment: The formula is ok, but you now need to compute P(A is final winner)

Comment: I know. I had model a solution a long time back. If I remember correctly I used the "Banach's matchbox problem" as a model.

Comment: See my answer. You only need the binomial distribution again.

Comment: If you mean the formula $\binom{18}{12}p^{12}\cdot (1-p)^6 + \cdots  \binom{18}{18}p^{18} \cdot (1-p)^0$, somehow I disagree

Answer (score 1):

Now use $p = 0.68256$

For A to be the final winner, she must win $\ge12$ of $18$ rounds.

You already know the formula to use.

**ps**

I had forgotten the Davis Cup analogy, where you play best of 5 matches ti the bitter end even if a team has won the first 3. So as reminded by Joriki, the simplified formula is

$$\binom{18}0p^{18}+\binom{18}1p^{17}q+\cdots+\binom{18}6p^{12}q^6$$

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. The competition may end playing just 12 rounds.

Comment: No misunderstanding, I am putting more explanation in answer as a ps.

Comment: @trueblueanil: a) The second coefficient should be $\binom{13}2$ (and the third could be equivalently but more clearly written as $\binom{17}6$). b) This is a needless complication; it's equal to $\binom{18}0p^{18}+\binom{18}1p^{17}q+\cdots+\binom{18}6p^{12}q^6$, so your original suggestion to just use the same approach as in the question was correct and better than the P.S. you added.

Comment: @nickchalkida: It doesn't matter whether the remaining games are played or not. In the calculation in your answer, you assumed that all $5$ games would be played, but the winner is the same if the round stops once the winner is determined, i.e. once one player has won $3$ games. Same here the other way around. "Best of five" and "first to win three" are just two different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: Your edit made it worse -- $\binom{17}{11}$ was correct (though the equivalent $\binom{17}6$ seems clearer).

Comment: @Joriki: Sorry for typos. I have changed as per your suggestion. The Davis Cup analogy had escaped my mind. Thanks.

Comment: I got a little bit confused. I think the before edit solution that anil gave, was correct. I now have doubts for this one, but if you agree then ok.

Comment: The answer I gave earlier (ignoring typos) was correct, but the key insight to the shorter method is that if A wins 12 **or more** rounds in 18 rounds, she wins anyway. After the twelfth win, it doesn't matter how many she wins or loses.

Comment: @nickchalkida: I'm not sure which edit you mean. The original post, which didn't contain a formula and suggested that you use the same approach that you used in your calculation in the question, was correct. All intermediate edits had typos, but other than that they suggested an equivalent (and thus also correct) but in my view unnecessarily complicated approach. The present version reverts to applying the approach you used in the question, and is correct.

Comment: @nickchalkida: Hi, returning to MSE after a long gap. If the answer has served your purpose, you should accept and close the question. If you still have doubts, pl. ask.